# Select cells while userform is open

Tags: excel, vba

I've made a very simple userform to help some students enter data into a table. It automatically moves down the table. However, if a the data is entered wrong or needs changing, you have to close the form, select the cell, then re-open the userform because you cant select cells with the userform open.

Is there a way (I presume in the properties?) to unlock the spreadsheet to allow to manually change the active cell?

Comment: Look at [modeless](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-userform/#ModelessUserform) userforms.

Comment: @Storax Simple! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
Userform.Show vbModeless
```